# Command that formats (prettifies) Elisp code

Tags: elisp, formatting

Let's say I have a function that looks like the following (as is often the case
when printing elisp output).

```
(defun my-example-function () (let ((a (do-something)) (b (do-something))) (setq someone me) (with-current-buffer b (do-that (or this (and that those))) (format "%s" a))))
```

**I would like a command that can turn that into something a human would write, such as the following.**

```
(defun my-example-function ()
  (let ((a (do-something))
        (b (do-something)))
    (setq someone me)
    (with-current-buffer b
      (do-that (or this (and that those)))
      (format "%s" a))))
```

**I understand that there's more than one way to format a piece of elisp
code**, and different human beings do it differently. Furthermore, I understand it's somewhat subjective. But it should be
fairly easy to come up with a set of rules that results in code that
is at least decent.

I actually tought of doing this myself a while ago, but I figured it's
better to ask before I reinvent the wheel.

*Note, I'm aware of the [pp](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/pp) function, but it doesn't quite get there:*

```
(defun my-example-function nil
  (let
      ((a
        (do-something))
       (b
        (do-something)))
    (setq someone me)
    (with-current-buffer b
      (do-that
       (or this
           (and that those)))
      (format "%s" a))))
```

Comment: Does this help? [Elisp Formatting](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/lisp_formatter.html)

Comment: Formatting is necessarily subjective. I'm not sure you could do better than a slightly better version of `pp`.

Comment: @King Thanks, it's certainly relevant.

Answer (score 16):

As others have suggested in comments, "formatting" can mean different things.

For *indentation* that is pretty conventional, try using `C-M-q` (command `indent-pp-sexp` in Lisp modes) with the cursor somewhere inside the top-level sexp that you want to re-indent (e.g. the `defun` sexp).

No, this is not "automatic" indentation, but it can become a habit to use it. ;-)

For things other than indentation you will need to either do it manually or roll your own "formatting" command(s) or find some existing such.

See also the Emacs manual, node Multi-line Indent and the Elisp manual, node `Mode-Specific Indent`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm quite happy with elisp indentation, I'm looking for something that knows when to break lines. :-) And yes I understand it's subjective. :-(

Comment: `M-q` (`fill-paragraph`) can sometimes be useful for line-breaking in Emacs-Lisp mode, depending on the context.  But you are probably looking for alignment as well...

Comment: @Malabarba see elisp-autofmt in my answer, this wraps/unwraps lines, respecting the fill column.

Answer (score 14):

Here's how [lispy](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy) re-formatted it for me
(by pressing <kbd>M</kbd> at either end of the expression):

```
(defun my-example-function ()
  (let ((a (do-something))
        (b (do-something)))
    (setq someone me)
    (with-current-buffer b (do-that (or this (and that those)))
                         (format "%s" a))))
```

To get from this to the formatting that you specified, press <kbd>qk C-m [</kbd>.

Comment: ```(local-set-key (kbd "s-8") #'lispy-multiline)
  (local-set-key (kbd "s-*") #'lispy-oneline)```

Comment: Why is pressing `M` does different formatting from directly executing `lispy-multiline`?

Answer (score 11):

Listing *Elisp* formatting tools here for completeness:

- [Elisp-Autofmt](https://codeberg.org/ideasman42/emacs-elisp-autofmt) Emacs integration to run on-save.
  Formats files following [this style](https://github.com/bbatsov/emacs-lisp-style-guide) by default (available on **melpa**).
- [lispy](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy) includes auto-formatting functionality (`lispy` on **melpa**)
- [ElispFormat](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispFormat) produces idiomatic elisp, but seems to have right-shift problems - going over the fill column width (`elisp-format` on **melpa**).
- [Grind](https://www.t3x.org/lisp64k/grinding.html) no Emacs integration (not on **melpa**).
- [Semantic Refactor](https://github.com/tuhdo/semantic-refactor/blob/master/srefactor-demos/demos-elisp.org) (`srefactor` on **melpa**)
- [Emacs 29+ `pp-emacs-lisp-code`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/156973639cc57dec47705f76f63c2ef3dc00a61d/etc/NEWS.29#L4554) (built-in, an extended pretty printer intended for use with code).

Comment: Has anyone tried Emacs 29 `pp-emacs-lisp-code` in macros to generate a docstring that includes the generate elisp code? It only seems able to insert text in the current buffer.

Comment: @ideasman42 Can you please provide documentation link regarding "pp-emacs-lisp-code"?

Comment: @RefaelSheinker [pp-emacs-lisp-code in Emacs NEWS file](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/156973639cc57dec47705f76f63c2ef3dc00a61d/etc/NEWS.29#L4554) (post edit is requested).