# Like JavaScript prettier but for Elisp

Tags: indentation, formatting, pretty-print

(N00b question.)

Is there command/package/snippet to format elisp code (like in my init file) in a standard(-ish) way, like what Prettier does for JavaScript?

I'm not only concerned about indentation, but keeping lines at max 80 chars, and whatever other general readability things are considered useful.

Comment: No.  Feel free to write such a thing, it's [way harder than it looks](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/09/08/the-hardest-program-ive-ever-written/).  Personally, I'd just deal with inserting newlines myself and let Emacs auto-indent the code.

Comment: lispy can do something towards your goal. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2235/4068

Comment: I get pretty good results just from `fill-paragraph` followed by re-indenting (I use Smartparens' `sp-indent-defun`).