# How to auto-format an Elisp file on save?

Tags: formatting, saving

Having used `clang-format` to format the buffer when saving, I find this functionality useful.

Are there tools to reformat an Elisp buffer when saving?

Comment: Here's what my search engine results turned up: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/283/command-that-formats-prettifies-elisp-code and https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispFormat and https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/elisp-format.el

Comment: I'm aware multiple tools for this exist which can probably be configured to format on save, I'm just not sure if any are very useful in practice, I tested `elisp-format` package which heavily indented my code ignoring it's own column width setting. And lispy looks like it can toggle between single/multi-line, but doesn't auto-format unless I missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since asking this question I've written an auto-formatter that runs on save.

Other elisp formatting tools I found caused a *lot* of right-shift and didn't seem well maintained.

See: [elisp-autofmt](https://codeberg.org/ideasman42/emacs-elisp-autofmt).

This can be configured to run for some projects and not others.
While this runs on save, it first checks for `.elisp-autofmt` before re-formatting the buffer.

---

[See other auto-formatting tools for reference.](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/55759/2418)